# How to authenticate with BigQuery from Apache Spark (pyspark)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery

I have create a `client id` and `client secret` for my bigquery project, but I don't know how to use those to successfully save a dataframe from a pyspark script to my bigquery table. My python code below results in the following error. Is there a way I can connect to BigQuery using the save options on the pyspark dataframe?

Code

```
df.write \
  .format("bigquery") \
  .option("client_id", "<MY_CLIENT_ID>") \
  .option("client_secret", "<MY_CLIENT_SECRET>") \
  .option("project", "bigquery-project-id") \
  .option("table", "dataset.table") \
  .save()
```

Error

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o93.save.
>   :
>   com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException:
>   400 Bad Request {   "error": "invalid_grant",   "error_description":
>   "Bad Request" }   at
>   com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:106)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.getTable(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:268)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$17.call(BigQueryImpl.java:664)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$17.call(BigQueryImpl.java:661)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.getTable(BigQueryImpl.java:660)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryInsertableRelation.getTable(BigQueryInsertableRelation.scala:68)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryInsertableRelation.exists(BigQueryInsertableRelation.scala:54)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException:
>   400 Bad Request {   "error": "invalid_grant",   "error_description":
>   "Bad Request" }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector) :

> **How do I authenticate outside GCE / Dataproc?**
>
> Use a service account JSON key and GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as
>   described [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started).
>
> Credentials can also be provided explicitly either as a parameter or
>   from Spark runtime configuration. It can be passed in as a
>   base64-encoded string directly, or a file path that contains the
>   credentials (but not both).

So you should be using this:

```
spark.read.format("bigquery").option("credentialsFile", "</path/to/key/file>")
```

Comment: Is there some other configs I need? I am now seeing this error: `Please set a project ID using the builder`

Comment: You can add it via options too. See all available [properties](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-bigquery-connector#properties)

Comment: please add this option too
.option("parentProject", "project-to-be-billed")